# Agora Web SDK mute/unmute button for remote user

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I am actually trying to implement a toggle button, which can mute/unmute remote audio. I am not getting a very good concept in agora docs. Got a code which is in stream-subscribed, how can I add mute unmute button to the remote video. Here is the code for mute the stream.

```
 client.on("stream-subscribed", function(evt){
   var stream = evt.stream;
   // Mutes the remote stream.
   stream.setAudioVolume(0);
 });
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code - it would be helpful to see what is triggering this event.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am looking for same solution.

Answer (score 2):

In Agora's WebSDK, muting audio/video a remote stream is the same as muting it on a local stream.

using your code, the snippet below will mute a stream as soon as a remote user successfully subscribes to it.

```
 client.on("stream-subscribed", function(evt){
   var stream = evt.stream;
   // Mutes the remote stream.
   stream.muteAudio();
 });
```

Update:

if you wish to unmute the stream, use: `unmuteAudio`

For a full list of the functions available for the `stream` object check out the Agora documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html

> Also keep in mind that the `stream` object in the Agora WebSDK is a WebRTC stream and can thus be used/manipulated in the same way.

Comment: What about unmute?